# BAT-file: FOR %%x variable incorrect expansion

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have bat-script with following code:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%g in ("%CFGFILE%") do (
  SET firstChar=%%g
  SET firstChar=!firstChar:~1,1!
  if /I "!firstChar!"=="#" (
    echo %%g>>"%INSTALL_PATH%\tmp.cfg"
  )else (
    if /I "%%g"=="document.folder" (
      SET path_written=TRUE
      echo %%g=%DOC_FOLDER%>>"%INSTALL_PATH%\tmp.cfg"
    )else (
      rem next line is buggy
      echo %%g=%%h>>"%INSTALL_PATH%\tmp.cfg"
    )
  )
)
```

The point is parsing cfg-file %CFGFILE% contents and copying every string without changes to new config-file, except only one string starting with "document.folder". This line must be changed. Problem is that the line after "next line is buggy" comment gives "c:\program files\myApp\original.cfg=" which is content of %CFGFILE% variable plus equals sign. Is this a bug or i've done something wrong? Is this connected with %%x variables visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mis-identified the source of the problem! :-)

Your problem is in the very first line - your FOR statement is processing a string, not a file, because the IN() clause is enclosed by double quotes. If you want the IN() clause to be treated as a quoted file name, then you need to add USEBACKQ to your FOR options.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%g in ("%CFGFILE%") do (
```

Just a heads up - even after the fix above, your code will not give the correct results if any of the following conditions appear

- If any line contains `!` then expansion of %%g or %%h will be corrupted because delayed expansion is enabled
- Commented # line will be incomplete if the original contained `=`
- Your normal lines will not be complete if there is a 2nd `=` in the original

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep in mind first thing in list. My comments do not contain = and this is simple key-value config, no second = allowed =). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

Use FART...
http://sourceforge.net/projects/fart-it/

Comment: The script is kind of installer. I'm already bringing to users desktop JRE. don't think it will be wise to use another tool user don't actually need. Thanks anyway.